# Why restarting the phone fixes the problem of Google Keep of not syncing the notes?

Tags: google, google-keep

That was the question only, because that happens to me a lot.
I work with keep in pc and android, and sometimes even if a have an Internet connection the notes are not syncing. And I wonder why this problem is fixed only by restarting the phone. Or better explained...
Why the process of restarting the device fix the syncing error?, so what's happening internally in the phone that's fixing the problem
Is this an app related issue?

Comment: Have you tried manually going into Settings - >Accounts >your Google account > Sync now instead of restarting the device?

Comment: No but maybe I formulated my question wrongly. What I mean is "Why the process of restarting the device fix the syncing error", so what's happening internally in the phone that's fixing the problem